# Regex preg_match() issues

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, delimiter

I cannot get the following regex to work properly:

```
preg_match('Currently: ([0-9\.km,]+)', $data, $matches)
```

The information inside of $data is: 'What it is Currently: 52,523' (along with about 30 lines of html).

I keep getting the following error: `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 49`

Note: Line 49 contains the preg_match that I posted above.

Edit: Apologies, i forgot to add in the matches parameter.

Answer (score 5):

the [preg_match function](https://www.php.net/preg_match) requires a delimiter in your pattern.

```
preg_match('/Currently: ([0-9\.km,]+)/', $data, $matches)
```

edit:

as described in the comments

> @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` If that is what you mean, yes I have set it. If i `echo $data`, it
> displays the webpage, which means it still contains all the html
> tags.. I'm not sure what to do from here, to use that data in my preg_

Then it's possible that `$data` contains white-spaces between: `Currently:` and `(...)`, so this should be considered in your pattern by adding `\s+` instead of a normal white-space, `\s` will match any white space character as described in the [PCRE regex syntax documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

```
preg_match('/Currently:\s+([0-9\.km,]+)/', $data, $matches)
```

Live test:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/xJNisE

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the same character at the begining and end of the pattern:

```
preg_match('/Currently: ([0-9\.km,]+)/', $data)
```

This character can't appear inside the pattern unless you escape it, for example:

```
preg_match('/<example><\/example>/', $xml)
```

You can use other characters as delimiters, one of the most used beside `/` is `#`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use delimiter like this edit

```
$data = 'What it is Currently: 52,523';
preg_match('&Currently: ([0-9\.km,]+)&', $data, $match);
print_r($match);
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/QGOoXT

Comment: I tried using this, and all that is returned is '1'. Am I missing something? I literally copy+pasted your above example.

Comment: @Woddles use the edited code . it will give the matched value.

Comment: @Woddles [preg_match](http://br2.php.net/preg_match) returns `1` if the *pattern* matches given *subject*, `0` if it does not, or `FALSE` if an error occurred. Check the link for the documentation ;)

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior I know i should've mentioned this in the post previous, so i will point it out now. I am using returning `$data = curl_exec($curl);`, which may be why my preg_match is returning `0`? I assume when using the preg_match on $data, it is failing because of additional html tags returned through `curl`. Any solution?

Comment: @Woddles did you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` with [`curl_setopt`](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)?

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` If that is what you mean, yes I have set it. If i `echo $data`, it displays the webpage, which means it still contains all the html tags.. I'm not sure what to do from here, to use that data in my preg_

Comment: @Woddles I've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859116/regex-preg-match-issues/13859176#13859176) to reflect that because the data that you are analyzing is possibly mismatching your regex because of white characters (space, `\n`, `\r`...)